# Evitar insercion en tabla dinamica

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla dinamica para los cheques que se entregan como forma de pago, como veran los datos no provienen de la bd.
Entonces tengo un boton agregar que añade un registro a la tabla, dentro del mismo registro aparece un boton confirmar:

```js
$("#agregarc").click(function(){
  
    var datoscheque='<tr><td><div>'+
    '<select id="bancos"><option value"=0">Seleccione<option></select></div></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nrocuenta" placeholder="CtaBancaria"/>'
    +'</td>'+
    
    '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="titular" placeholder="Titular"/></td>'+
  +'<div>'+'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="CUIT" placeholder="CUIT"/></td>'+
  '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="Importe" placeholder="Son pesos"/></td>'
    +
    '<td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechacobro"placeholder="Deposito el:"/></td>'+
 
    '<td><button id="acreditar" class="btn btn-primary"><span id="acreditar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button></td><td></td></tr>';

$(datoscheque).appendTo("#cheques");
    listarbancos(); 


  
  $("#acreditar").click(function(){
  
    var Banco=$("#bancos").val();
    var Importe=$("#Importe").val();

    var nroCuenta=$("#nrocuenta").val();
    var titular=$("#titular").val();
    var fechacobro=$("#fechacobro").val();
    var CUIT=33;
    var cobrado=0;
    var d = new Date();
    var fecharecibo=d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate();
   
    
     $.ajax({
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/ingresacheque.php",
                                                        data: { "idbanco":Banco,"idc":idcliente,"num":nroCuenta,"fechar":fecharecibo,"fechac":fechacobro,"importe":Importe,"titular":titular,"cuenta":nroCuenta,"cobrado":cobrado,"CUIT":CUIT},
                                                   
                                            
                                                        error: function(){
                                                            alert("error petición ajax");
                                                           
                                                        },
                                                        
                                                        success: function(data){
                                                         
                                                            console.log(data); 
   

      
    
    var Bancot=$("#bancos").find('option:selected').text();
    var nroCuenta=$("#nrocuenta").val();
    var titular=$("#titular").val();
    var fechacobro=$("#fechacobro").val();
    var cuit=$("#CUIT").val();
    var importe=$("#Importe").val();
 
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(0)").html(Bancot);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(1)").html(nroCuenta);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(2)").html(titular);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(3)").html(cuit);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(4)").html(importe);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(5)").html(fechacobro);
 $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(6)").html('<td><button class="btn btn-primary "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td><td>'+
'<button class="eliminar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td><td>');

  $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
   
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();


});
                                                                }
                                                        
                                                    });
    $("#cheques").val(Importe);
});
});
```

Lo que quiero es evitar que se agregue un registro si no se confirmo el anterior.

Comment: Cual es el botón de confirmar???

Comment: seria el acreditar que aparece ahi..este agrega una nueva fila pero ya con los datos ingresados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun entendi quieres solo agregar una nueva fila si al ultimo registro que añadistes dinamicamente a la tabla se acreditó. Para saber si puedes agregar uno nuevo basado en este criterio pueden darse 2 casos, que tu tabla aun no tenga registros o que ya hayas acreditado por tanto la ultima celda de tu ultima fila no va a contener el botón con el id `acreditar` ya que modificas su html. Sabiendo esto puedes modificar tu codigo y que quede como esto:

```js
$("#agregarc").click(function(){
  
    var datoscheque='<tr><td><div>'+
    '<select id="bancos"><option value"=0">Seleccione<option></select></div></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nrocuenta" placeholder="CtaBancaria"/>'
    +'</td>'+
    
    '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="titular" placeholder="Titular"/></td>'+
  +'<div>'+'<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="CUIT" placeholder="CUIT"/></td>'+
  '<td><input type="text"class="form-control" id="Importe" placeholder="Son pesos"/></td>'
    +
    '<td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechacobro"placeholder="Deposito el:"/></td>'+
 
    '<td><button id="acreditar" class="btn btn-primary"><span id="acreditar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button></td><td></td></tr>';

    var acreditado = ($("#cheques tbody tr:last").find('button#acreditar').length === 0 || $("#cheques tbody tr").length === 0);
    if(acreditado){
       $(datoscheque).appendTo("#cheques");
       listarbancos(); 
    }

  $("#acreditar").click(function(){
  
    var Banco=$("#bancos").val();
    var Importe=$("#Importe").val();

    var nroCuenta=$("#nrocuenta").val();
    var titular=$("#titular").val();
    var fechacobro=$("#fechacobro").val();
    var CUIT=33;
    var cobrado=0;
    var d = new Date();
    var fecharecibo=d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate();
   
    
     $.ajax({
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/ingresacheque.php",
                                                        data: { "idbanco":Banco,"idc":idcliente,"num":nroCuenta,"fechar":fecharecibo,"fechac":fechacobro,"importe":Importe,"titular":titular,"cuenta":nroCuenta,"cobrado":cobrado,"CUIT":CUIT},
                                                   
                                            
                                                        error: function(){
                                                            alert("error petición ajax");
                                                           
                                                        },
                                                        
                                                        success: function(data){
                                                         
                                                            console.log(data); 
   

      
    
    var Bancot=$("#bancos").find('option:selected').text();
    var nroCuenta=$("#nrocuenta").val();
    var titular=$("#titular").val();
    var fechacobro=$("#fechacobro").val();
    var cuit=$("#CUIT").val();
    var importe=$("#Importe").val();
 
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(0)").html(Bancot);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(1)").html(nroCuenta);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(2)").html(titular);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(3)").html(cuit);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(4)").html(importe);
    $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(5)").html(fechacobro);
 $("#cheques tbody tr:last td:eq(6)").html('<td><button class="btn btn-primary "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td><td>'+
'<button class="eliminar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td><td>');

  $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
   
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();


});
                                                                }
                                                        
                                                    });
    $("#cheques").val(Importe);
});
});
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto estimado muchas gracias!!